# How to create a RabbitMQ user using the RabbitMQ API from a c# console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, console-application

I am working on a Hashicorp Vault management .net-core 3.1.3 console application written in C#. I have been tasked with creating a RabbitMQ user on an MQ server from the console app utilizing the RabbitMQ restful API. I have zero experience with this API. I have been reading the documentation but still don't have a clue as to how to begin.
I have limited experience with APIs in general and have never tried to do anything like this from a console app.
Any guidance or example code would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.
Matt

Comment: Progress: Installed curl nuget. Experimenting with this now.

Comment: Progress: Going with built in HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the clue-bat Adam. Here is where I ended up, and works well.

```
try
{
    // Set MQ server credentials
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("mqUserName", "mqPassword");

    // Instantiate HttpClientHandler, passing in the NetworkCredential
    HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = networkCredential };

    // Instantiate HttpClient passing in the HttpClientHandler
    using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

    // Get the response from the API endpoint.
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://YourServer:AndPort/api/users/");

    // Get the response content.
    HttpContent httpContent = httpResponseMessage.Content;

    // Get the stream of the content.
    using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(await httpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync());

    // Get the output string.
    string returnedJsonString = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

    // Instantiate a list to loop through.
    List<string> mqAccountNames = new List<string>();

    if (returnedJsonString != "")
    {
        // Deserialize into object
        dynamic dynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnedJsonString);
        if (dynamicJson != null)
        {
            foreach (dynamic item in dynamicJson)
            {
                mqAccountNames.Add(item.name.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    bool accountExists = false;

    foreach (string mqAccountName in mqAccountNames)
    {
        if (mqAccountName == userName)
        {
            accountExists = true;
        }
    }

    switch (accountExists)
    {
        case true:
            Console.WriteLine("This user already exists on the MQ server.");
            break;
        case false:
            // Create the new user on the MQ Server
            Console.WriteLine("This user will be created on the MQ server.");
                        
            string uri = $"http://YourServer:AndPort/api/users/{userName}";

            MqUser mqUser = new MqUser
            {
                password = password,
                tags = "administrator"
            };

            string info = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mqUser);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(info, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PutAsync(uri, content);
            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error creating the MQ user account.");
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                return false;
            }

            uri = $"http://YourServer:AndPort/api/permissions/%2F/{userName}";

            MqPermissions mqPermissions = new MqPermissions
            {
                configure = ".*",
                write = ".*",
                read = ".*"
            };

            info = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mqPermissions);
            content = new StringContent(info, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PutAsync(uri, content);

            if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error creating the permissions on the MQ user account.");
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                return false;
            }

            break;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

I created simple MqUser and MqPermissions classes so I could just JsonConvert.SerializeObject to pass the info.
Another weird thing was that my company chose to name the MQ Virtual Host as "/".
This had not been an issue up to this point as we had never tried to use the API before.
Since the / character is expected in a uri, this was a hangup, but I tried encoding it as %2F and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the RabbitMQ Management HTTP API, the docs for which are [here](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.8.7/priv/www/api/index.html). Specifically you'll want to `PUT` a user on the `/api/users/name` endpoint.

There are many ways to make an HTTP request in c#, the simplest is probably the WebRequest class as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netcore-3.1). You'll need to [set the method to PUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.method?view=netcore-3.1), [write your json payload to the request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststream?view=netcore-3.1) and [set your rabbitmq credentials for the request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.credentials?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Additionally, Microsoft has an HttpClient in C# .NET console app walkthrough here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient


If OP is okay with another dependency, I've found RestSharp to be the most convenient C# HTTP client experience: https://restsharp.dev/